# Delete Operators and they equatable to a destructor in C++

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

This is probably a simple question, but: If a program uses the delete operator, is a destructor not needed? This is in "C++".

Comment: `delete` calls the destructor. User-defined destructors are rarely needed anyway, though, and neither is `delete`ing something.

Comment: What do you mean by uses a `delete` operator and destructor not needed? You get always a free destructor from the compiler. Also `delete` should go together with a `new` operator while the destructor goes together with the constructor.

Comment: I feel a rule of three reference coming...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Self-fulfilling prophesy in action!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delete operator is not a substitute for a destructor...it will cause the destructor to be invoked.

The compiler will supply a default destructor, if you do not define one yourself.  Whether
the default destructor is sufficient, or whether you need to supply your own, is a
completely separate issue from whether you use the delete operator explicitly, or
merely allow the object to go out of scope.

Edit: Since Michael Dorgan mentioned it, I might as well add this:

[Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)

> The rule of three (also known as the Law of The Big Three or The Big
>   Three) is a rule of thumb in C++ that claims that if a class defines
>   one of the following it should probably explicitly define all three:
>
> ```
> destructor
> copy constructor
> copy assignment operator
> ```

Comment: It's several years too late to be teaching the Rule of Three.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4782757/103167

Comment: Perhaps, but not completely and I will also add that many locations are not allowed to code in C++11 yet so it still has much value.